# How to change text color of a MaskedTextBox on TextChange event?

Tags: c#, winforms, maskedtextbox

I have following class derived from MaskedTextBox.
When the length of the text entered is less than the predefined text (`000000000000`, with length of 12), I want highlight the text in red, otherwise in green.

In my custom MaskedTextBox class, if the length of entered text is not 12 (not valid), I try to change the text color to either red or green in the `OntextChange` method override.
But the code I wrote does not work.

The color is always red and it does not change.

```
public partial class MFMaskedTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox
{
    private int lengthdefaultetext;

    protected override void OnCreateControl()
    {
        base.OnCreateControl();
        this.Mask = "0000-0000-0000";
        this.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 16);
        this.TextMaskFormat = System.Windows.Forms.MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;
        this.Text = "000000000000";
        lengthdefaultetext = this.Text.Length;
        this.ForeColor= System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
        if (this.Text.Length != lengthdefaultetext)
        {
            this.ForeColor= System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            this.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs eventargs) {
        base.OnClick(eventargs);
        this.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: What value to you enter in the textbox? Does it change to red when you enter 2 characters in the textbox?

Comment: I just enter digits. the color is red, because of this line.(this.ForeColor= System.Drawing.Color.Red;) and does  not change. It seems this.ForeColor= System.Drawing.Color.Red; does not work completely.

Comment: It seems this.ForeColor= System.Drawing.Color.Red; does not work completely in textchangeevent function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting the PromptChar, while the Control's Text (`000000000000`) is added right away, so `lengthdefaultetext` is always different than the Text length (12 and 14 respectively).

Set the PromptChar to the intended `'0'` char (`this.PromptChar = '0'`), set [ResetOnPrompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.resetonprompt) to `false` so it doesn't override [AllowPromptAsInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.allowpromptasinput) (`true` as default) and use the [MaskFull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.maskfull) or [MaskCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.maskcompleted) properties to verify whether the Mask has been filled, setting the color based on the value returned.

[InsertKeyMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.insertkeymode) is set to `InsertKeyMode.Overwrite`, to allow to overwrite the existing `0` chars (no need to delete one to input a new value when the Text is full).

► Moved the properties settings to the Control's default constructor. You should always have a default constructor. `OnCreateControl` or `OnHandleCreated` can be used to get/set properties that depends on the Control's handle existence (or its existence in relation to a container).

If these *numbers* have special meaning when inserted in a specific sequence, you can create a custom [MaskedTextProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.maskedtextprovider) to validate the input against the Mask. A custom Provider can only be specified as argument in a [MaskedTextBox constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.-ctor).

```
using System.Drawing
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class MFMaskedTextBox : MaskedTextBox
{
    public MFMaskedTextBox()
    {
        Font = new Font("Arial", 16);
        InsertKeyMode = InsertKeyMode.Overwrite;
        ResetOnPrompt = false;
        TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;

        PromptChar = '0';
        Text = "000000000000";
        Mask = "0000-0000-0000";
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
        ForeColor = MaskCompleted ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked! this is exactly i want and it is more.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the TextChange event handler **OnCreateControl**

```
this.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.OnTextChanged);
```

Comment: The OP is using a custom Control derived from MaskedTextBox and they're correctly overriding `OnTextChanged`. You don't usually subscribe to events in a derived control. Consumers of these controls do.